# AppsScript - how to get input from CardService.TextInput objects

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently trying to create an add on to better assist the copying of files in google drive. I cant seem to get any clear answers on how to get the inputted values from TextInput objects. I want to use the input to get the link, for the folder the user wants the file to be pasted into. Any clear answers on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a newTextInput that's used in a function called saveNote(e)

```
var commentText=CardService.newTextInput()
  .setFieldName('Comments')
  .setMultiline(true)
  .setTitle('Comments');
  section.addWidget(commentText);
  var action=CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('saveNote');
```

You can get the text with e.formInput.Comments where Comments is the fieldName

```
function saveNote(e){
  var row=[];
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Denver", "E MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  row.push(ts,e.formInput.Note_Type,e.formInput.Comments,Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
```

[newTextInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input#setFieldName(String))

Documentation says:

> Sets the key that identifies this text input in the event object that is generated when there is a UI interaction.